# Paho MQTT Client: Best Practice for subscribing to multiple Topics

Tags: spring, spring-integration, mqtt, messaging, paho

Our usecase is that multiple assets send different types of data (let's say `status`, `temp` and `data`) to a MQTT broker. Because message brokers are very good at routing, handling topics, etc., the assets publish each type of data to a dedicated topic:

```
status messages   >   status topic   >   e.g. /asset/123/status
temp messages     >   temp topic     >   e.g. /asset/123/temp
data messages     >   data topic     >   e.g. /asset/123/data
```

Now our question came up, how the subscriber should handle the different topics. We therefore use the default Paho client via SpringIntegration. In our minds, there are two possible solutions to this:

**Solution 1**

One Paho client subscribes to all the respective topics. Now the actual routing (which callback for which type of data) must be done in the backend itself.

[image: 1]

**Solution 2**

One Paho client for each topic. So the actual routing is done at the message broker and no routing logic must be done in the backend anymore. The clients simply call their callback and the backend just focuses on its domain logic (not on the routing of topics).

[image: 2]

**Best Practise?**

Now our question is, are there any best practices concerning this question? From our perspective, routing is the job of the message broker, because this is what is is designed for. So the routing logic should not be within the backend. That's good because the backend can now concentrate on its own domain logic. But for this, we would need to have `n` clients, with `n` being the amount of different data types. This could possibly let the connections explode when, at some point of time, having more and more message types and therefore more and more topics.

Are there any best practices, benchmarks or (anti) pattern covering this topic?

Comment: First best practice, do not start your topics with a leading `/` it will just lead to problems down the line (e.g. when you start using shared subscriptions)

Comment: Oh, that was just a "typo" within the diagram. But thanks for the notice anyway. Sure the topics are like `asset/#/status` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented more Solution 2 than Solution 1 in similar cases. As you rightly point out, the backends can just focus on their singular use cases, and not have to worry about the others.....if that is really the case.  If at some point down the road, you need `/status` along with `/data`, then that becomes a problem you would not have with Solution 1.  Solution 2 takes more compute resources, but is usually faster (depending on your MQTT broker and what your solution is running on.)  Solution 2 is also better for things like troubleshooting and bugs that cause crashes -- A crash only affects the one domain, not all of them.